# Ant shortcut for specifying source/version in several different javac tasks

Tags: java, ant

When using ant, is there a way to specify a set of attribute/value pairs that can be passed to different tasks as a single item/variable?

I have an ant build file that includes several different javac tasks.  All have the same values for several attributes (source, version, bootclasspath, debug, etc.)

I know that I can set a variable for each attribute; but, is there a way I can refer to the entire group of attributes so I can do something like this

```
<javac ${standard_attributes} ...>
```

instead of

```
<javac debug="on" includeantruntime="false" source="${java_version}" target="${java_version}" bootclasspath="${bcp}" ...
```

in every javac task?

Answer (score 0):

Use `presetdef`

`<presetdef name="standard-javac">
    <javac debug="on" includeantruntime="false" source="${java_version}" target="${java_version}" bootclasspath="${bcp}" ...
    </javac>
  </presetdef>`

and then use `standard-javac` as a task in all places where you used to put `javac`.